# Protecting my self from cross-site scripting

Tags: asp.net, .net, request, xss

I have implemented a `Request.QueryString["somestr"].ToString();`

I suppress cross site scripting by doing `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["somestr"].ToString();`

I still have an issue where a user can do:

myfriendlydomain.com/?somestr=';alert(WOO XSS SUCCEDED);test='

How can I prevent this from happening?

As requested:

```
//Code Behind
if(request.querystring["somestr"] != null)
{
  AffiliatesEmail = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["somestr"].ToString();    
}

//Front End
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    /*** Do not change ***/
    var SomeVAR = {};
    SomeVAR.Tracking.Sale.orderRef = '<%= AffiliatesEmail %>';
  //]]>
</script>

<script src="https://www.somethirdparty.com/somejscript.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"> </script>
```

This is our implementation. Anything afterwards I do not believe is relevant.

Comment: The pertinent info here is _how_ the injection can still succeed - you must be writing it to the page somewhere, because simply appending it to the querystring isn't enough to make it work. Let us know what you do with `Request.QueryString["somestr"].ToString();`

Comment: But we still can't tell where this string ends up. What is `AffiliatesEmail`? Where do its contents go to enable an XSS attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [JavaScriptStringEncode() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx) to scrub the string and encode it to prevent this from happening.

Another way is to use the [AntiXSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) library.

Comment: JavaScriptStringEncode() Method is a .net framework .4.0 function we are still on .net framework 3.5 until further notice.

Comment: Yeah your right, the other solution is just quicker to implement, I am constrained by time I shouldnt say that I sound like a short cut dev.

Answer (score 1):

By knowing the context in which you are using the `AffiliatesEmail` string, it helps to know how thorough you have to be in validating and sanitising the string.

Let's say for example, that we know `AffiliatesEmail` was only valid if it were numeric. That way, you'd be protected if you rejected any `Request.QueryString["somestr"]` which didn't validate as a number.

Now, I suspect that `AffiliatesEmail` is in fact supposed to be a valid email address.

Using that knowledge, we can now validate it as an email address and reject everything else:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
try
{       
    MailAddress ma = new MailAddress(AffiliatesEmail);
}
catch (FormatException fe)
{
    //Email isn't valid, so don't output it to the client!!!
}
```

The code above simply validates whether the string is an email address (as defined by .NET) - if it's not, then we don't need to worry about what it ***is***, because we simply don't trust it.

So don't get too hung up on santising everthing that gets put in the querystring - by simply knowing the bounds of what is acceptable, you can avoid complex regexes and XSS-cleaning routines.

Comment: Shark and Widor answers are relevant. I used this one.

Comment: Wow. Input validation is NOT the correct solution here. See the list of valid letters in email addresses here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address
What happens if the attacker enters the email address:
joe'+alert(xss)+'@evil.com

Comment: Good point Erlend, I am going to try decompile the .net 4.0 framework in my spare time to try get the JavaScript String Encode method

Comment: @Erlend OK, good point, although `joe'+alert(xss)+'@evil.com` isn't valid JavaScript syntax in this context, so you don't need to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate every querystring input to make sure you have valid data coming in. I wouldn't write the value directly out to a page, either.

Comment: Validate as in check its not something it should not be. So if it should be only ever aaa, bbb, ccc then check if it is that if not then reject it.

Comment: Right - in this case I'd probably go with a regular expression to make sure you're getting an email in. Otherwise reject the data.

Comment: This is really hard to get right. The input can contain an attack and still be a valid email address.